Is it possible to convert a site collection that uses Windows Claims, to one that leverages OIDC in SPSE?
We are working on building a SPSE farm with Web Applications that should leverage OIDC to talk to EntraID for authentication. We currently have SP2019 Farms using Kerberos/WindowsAuth (Classic Windows Claims) that we would need to upgrade/migrate.
Question is, if we are able to leverage either Convert-SPWebApplication or Move-SPUser to get the users migrated to using OIDC on the new farm after the Content Databases are migrated to SPSE..
has anyone implemented this before?
We have been testing the integration of EntraID with SP2019, and have gotten to a point where we realized that we cannot use Convert-SPWebApplication to migrate our CDBs and would have to leverage Move-SPUser, and since it is farm wide, we would need to build a new farm to not break the existing webapps... We were thinking that if we are going to build a new farm, why not go to SPSE and take advantage of OIDC instead...
